# Format of printing bits in C

Tags: c, format, bit

I'm working on a project on multithreading. It's all about a robot maze. Now, I need to convert the value of chRobotCmdStatus to an 8-bit format. chRobotCmdStatus is a global variable.

This is my code:

```
void charToBit(char character)
{
    char output[9] = "00000000";
    itoa(character, output, 2);
    printf("%s\n", output);
}

// Control Thread
unsigned int __stdcall ControlThread(void* arg){
    printf("Control Thread 1 \n");
    printf("\n VALUE OF: %d", gchRobotCmdStatus);
    charToBit(gchRobotCmdStatus);

    return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
VALUE OF: 00
```

It needs to be:

```
VALUE OF: 0000 0000
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can pad with zero by using `%#8f`

Comment: `itoa` is not a standard C function.

Comment: I just made my charToBit function to this: int i;
 for (i=0; i < 8; i++){
  printf("\n %d", !!((character << i) & 0x80));
 } and it worked.

Comment: It's convenient to learn to read hex as binary in your head, then you can just write `printf("\n VALUE OF: %x"`) and save screen space too. There's only 16 cases to learn.

Comment: how is [tag:multithreading] relevant here?

Comment: I'm working on a project about multithreading @FelixPalmen sorry for the tag

Answer (score 2):

```
void charToBit(char ch)
{
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        putchar( (ch & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0' );
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `flag` and `field width` properties of [`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf). Assuming `gchRobotCmdStatus` is an `int` and hold the binary *representation* which you you want to be printed in an 8-bit pattern, you can use, for example,

```
 printf("\n VALUE OF: %08d", gchRobotCmdStatus);
```

to print

> VALUE OF: 0000 0000

Comment: @MohitJain Well, `gchRobotCmdStatus` has to hold the _binary_ representation. I guess the original code does the same.

Comment: Looking at function `charToBit` and use of `itoa` (Not standard but available on many compilers as extension, it appears questioner is suffering with missing leading `0`s which is expected behavior of `itoa`

Answer (score 1):

I just changed my function from

```
void charToBit(char character)
{
    char output[9] = "00000000";
    itoa(character, output, 2);
    printf("%s\n", output);
}
```

to

```
void charToBit(char character)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < 8; i++){
        printf("\n %d", !!((character << i) & 0x80));
    }
}
```

and it worked.

Comment: `printf("\n %d",...` called 8 times will not produce "0000 0000".

Comment: @chux Why? This looks reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `%d` with `%s` in your `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
itoa(character, output, 2);
```

This will put a null terminator after producing the 2 bytes for the string.

You will need a different method of converting the binary value to string.

Answer (score 0):

This produces required output:

```
void charToBit(char ch)
{
    static char* bits[] = 
    {
        "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
        "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"
    };
    printf("%s %s\n", bits[ch >> 4 & 0xf], bits[ch & 0xf]);
}
```